# Is scala.actors package gone?

Tags: scala, actor, scala-2.10

Can not find scala.actors package in latest milestones, while it still presents in scaladocs:
https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.0-M6

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The scala-actors library is now a separate artifact. You can add it to your project like

```
"org.scala-lang" % "scala-actors" % "2.10.0-M6"
```

It is online here:

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/org/scala-lang/scala-actors/2.10.0-M6/

Comment: As I understand, the library pointed out in the answer is Akka. But where is the ActorSystem object gone? Has anyone seen it? Is there something else you need to add (besides scala-actors) to get the full Akka lib?